# circle of images and rotate them according to mouse wheel - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I would like to build a functionality to let the user rotate the circle wheel using mouse and select an image. How can i build something like this? is there any plugin available for this?

[**Please see design image here**](http://202.53.11.62/skin.png)

Answer (score 1):

This can achieved by following ways.
1) create a Parent div and add Bigger circle as a background.
2) Add Small Circles as child element and to arrange the circle as mention , you need to apply rotate and translate CSS property. **Refer** [link](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/astro/) **for this purpose only**

3) Then add event mouse over, mouse down and mouse up event to Parent DIV. Apply rotate and translate CSS property on mouse down.**For this Refer** [link](http://cubiq.org/rotating-wheel-for-your-iphone-webapps) Pls note that you will not be able to test the given link on desktop browser as the code is having TOUCH EVENTS, **need to convert touch events to Mouse event** to achieve the same but this code could be tested on iphone.